# Access file from PHP backend

Tags: php, angular, file-upload

I have a simple application with an Angular front end and a PHP backend. I am uploading a file in the front end and need to process it in the backend.
My angular code looks like,

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.selectedFile, 'transaction_file');
    this.http.post('http://localhost/MyBackend/index.php', formData).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      alert('success!');
    });
```

And in the `index.php` of my backend project I am trying to access this file with,

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

but this $postdata seems to be null. Any idea how to get this file in the backend is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is `this.http` but it looks like you are creating `POST` request which can be in PHP handled with variable `$_POST` and files are in `$_FILES` variable.

---

> **$_POST** 
>   An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
>   source: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

---

> **$_FILES** 
>   An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
>   source: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

---

There is [basic php file upload tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) on w3schools.com.

Comment: I tried with $_FILES but it seems empty. And yes my this.http is an angular HttpClient object and it is sending a post request to php backend